# If $H \cap [-1,1]$ is finite and contains a nonzero element, prove that $H$ is a cyclic subgroup of $(\mathbb{R},+)$.

Tags: group-theory

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $(\mathbb{R},+)$ such that $H \cap [-1,1]$ is a finite set containing a nonzero element. Show that $H$ is cyclic.

I think that if I somehow prove $H \cap [-1,1] = \{-1,0,1\}$, then I should be able to prove that $H$ is the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Your attempt to prove it won't work because the subgroup need not contain $1$ or $-1$.

Comment: then how should i proceed.any hint

Comment: No, sorry, I'm going to bed now.

Comment: Since $H \cap [-1,1]$ is finite, and contains a non-zero element, it contains a non-zero element of smallest absolute value, say $h$. Show that $\Bbb Zh \subseteq H$. Now show that if $x \in H -  \Bbb Zh$, you can find $y \in H$ with $0 < |y| < h$.

Comment: @David Wheeler thanks .i got it

Answer (score 0):

Since $\{0\}\cup T= H \cap [-1,1]$ is finite [$0 \not\in T$, $\emptyset \subsetneq T$], so we can completely enumerate $T$. Let $T =\{a_1, a_2, ..., a_m\} $ be the complete 'list' of elements. Let $Q= \{a_i \in T: a_i>0 \}$ and $a_t$ be the minimal element in $Q$.

Claim: $H=\langle a_t \rangle $.

Suppose, the claim is false. Then for some $h \in H$, $h \notin \langle a_t \rangle $. [we pick $h$ such that it is $>0$. If not, then we pick $-h$].

So, we can find a positive integer $p$ such that $p a_t< h <(p+1)a_t \implies 0<h-pa_t<a_t $ which contradicts the fact that $a_t$ is the minimal element in $Q$.